# save multi checkbox by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am working with live checkbox, so when I need to put ON(1) or OFF(0) one checkbox immediately the checkbox update the value in the DB and all is ok...but now I am working with live checkbox in a user list(which I already have right now 100 users)...so the problem is when I try to put someone a ban, the checkbox just only works with the last one and not in the others users... can you please help me?

Here is the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="ban" id="ban">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
     <?php if ($row['banned'] == '1') { 
         echo '<input type="checkbox" name="banned" data-no-uniform="true" class="iphone-toggle" value="on" checked>';
         } else {
         echo '<input type="checkbox" name="banned" data-no-uniform="true" class="iphone-toggle" value="off" >';
         } ?>
</form>
<div id="gif" style="display:none;" align="center"><img src="img/ajax-loaders/ajax-loader-1.gif" /></div>
```

Here the JS:

```
$("#ban").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"includes/ban.php?ts=" + new Date().getTime(),
    dataType:"text",
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    beforeSend:function(){
      $("#gif").show();
    },
    success:function(response){
        $("#gif").hide();
    } 
  })
  return false;
});
```

And this is the code to DB:

```
<?php
include('con.php');
if($_POST['banned']==on) {
    try{
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $banned = '0';
        $sql = "UPDATE BANS SET 
        banned = :banned
        WHERE id= :id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':banned', $banned, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "<div class='alert alert-block alert-success fade in'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                the ban is off!.
            </div>";
    }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    try{
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $banned = '1';
        $sql = "UPDATE BANS SET 
        banned = :banned
        WHERE id= :id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':banned', $banned, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "<div class='alert alert-block alert-danger fade in'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                the ban is on!
            </div>";
    }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
$dbh = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason only the last one is getting submitted is because you can't assign the same id to multiple elements.

Change: `<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="ban" id="ban">`

To: `<form class="form-horizontal ban" method="post">`

Then update your jQuery selector to `$("form.ban")`

Finally, in your PHP: `if($_POST['banned']==on) {`
Should be: `if($_POST['banned']=='on') {`

Edit: As a side-note, the same problem will affect the AJAX loader GIF, assuming again that you have an AJAX loader in each row, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Your solution will work fine, though as a suggestion for joaquin to make the overall code simpler, is the Form at all required. If he needs to update the user status on Checkbox click there can be just the checkbox without the form and have a data attribute as the user id. Then the click on any checkbox can be handled and processed just like it is being done as of now.

Comment: @Ben Chamberlin nice!, thank you, now is working!...and yes the AJAX loader still show me only in the first one...